# Multiprocessing in Python blocks when asked to run

Tags: python, queue, multiprocessing

I am developing a program that does a polling and I need the polling to be done in a separate process for performance reasons.
The program is pretty long, but I managed to reduce it to a minimum so it easier to understand. It is a two states machine, one idle and the other prints values that the separate process has put in a queue.

So the problem is that when order the multiprocessing process to Start, everything freezes. Only the process is running like crazy and the program does not react.

```
self.queue = Queue() #initialize a Queue
self.slave_process = Process(
    target=self.write,
    args =(self.queue,)) #Define our queue filler process
# Here is when it freezes
self.slave_process.start() #Ask the process to start
```

Please look at the code commentaries for further explanation.

Would you help me out with this?

```
import time
import threading
import tkinter as tk
from datetime import datetime
from multiprocess import Process
from multiprocessing import Queue

class Main(object):

    # This is a very normal object initializer
    # I will use a tkinter GUI to use a button
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk() #The root of tkinter
        self.button1 = tk.Button(self.root, 
            text="Connect", command=self.btConnect,
            padx=5, pady=5) #My button that executes btConnect()
        self.button1.pack() #We pack the button
        self.state = "idle" #Indicator of the initial state of the FSM
        self.root.mainloop() #Instruction to make tkinter GUI run

    # This state does pretty much nothing except print its name
    # It should terminate when the self.state name changes
    def stIdle(self):
        while self.state == "idle":
            print("stIdle")

    # This state prints its name and, 
    # if there is a value in the queue it pops it and prints it
    def stConnect(self):
        while state == "connected":
            print("stConnect")
            if not self.queue.empty():
                print(self.queue.get())

    # This is the code the button executes
    def btConnect(self):
        print("acConnect") #First print something so we know it happened
        if self.state == "idle": #if the state was idle
            self.queue = Queue() #initialize a Queue
            self.slave_process = Process(
                target=self.write,
                args =(self.queue,)) #Define our queue filler process
            # Here is when it freezes
            self.slave_process.start() #Ask the process to start
            time.sleep(0.250) # Give the process some time to fill the queue
            if not queue.empty(): # If is not empty then go to stConnect
                self.state = "connected"
                self.stConnect()
                #threading.Thread(name="idle", target=self.stConnect).start()
                # I would like to run stConnect in a thread, but for now OK
        elif state == "connected":
            # Idealistically I would like that hitting the button again
            # would terminate the process, but for now is OK
            self.state = "idle"
            self.slave_process.terminate()
            self.stIdle()
            #threading.Thread(name="idle", target=self.stIdle).start()

    def write(self, queue):
        while True:
            print("write")
            queue.put("QUEUE")

Main()
```

I edited the code, changed the process.run() to process.start() and now it tells me this error as well as opening a new tkinter instance:

```
C:\Users\U4928\Documents\workspace\RawData>C:\Programs_RD\Python\Python36-32\python.exe test.py
acConnect
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Programs_RD\Python\Python36-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1702, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "test.py", line 39, in btConnect
    self.slave_process.start()
  File "C:\Programs_RD\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\multiprocess\process.py", line 112, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "C:\Programs_RD\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\multiprocess\context.py", line 223, in _Popen
    return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Programs_RD\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\multiprocess\context.py", line 322, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Programs_RD\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\multiprocess\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 65, in __init__
    reduction.dump(process_obj, to_child)
  File "C:\Programs_RD\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\multiprocess\reduction.py", line 63, in dump
    ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
  File "C:\Programs_RD\Python\Python36-32\lib\pickle.py", line 437, in dump
    self.save(obj)
  File "C:\Programs_RD\Python\Python36-32\lib\pickle.py", line 549, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "C:\Programs_RD\Python\Python36-32\lib\pickle.py", line 662, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "C:\Programs_RD\Python\Python36-32\lib\pickle.py", line 504, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "C:\Programs_RD\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\dill\_dill.py", line 893, in save_module_dict
    StockPickler.save_dict(pickler, obj)
  File "C:\Programs_RD\Python\Python36-32\lib\pickle.py", line 856, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.items())
  File "C:\Programs_RD\Python\Python36-32\lib\pickle.py", line 882, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "C:\Programs_RD\Python\Python36-32\lib\pickle.py", line 504, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "C:\Programs_RD\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\dill\_dill.py", line 1069, in save_instancemethod0
    pickler.save_reduce(MethodType, (obj.__func__, obj.__self__), obj=obj)
  File "C:\Programs_RD\Python\Python36-32\lib\pickle.py", line 638, in save_reduce
    save(args)
  File "C:\Programs_RD\Python\Python36-32\lib\pickle.py", line 504, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "C:\Programs_RD\Python\Python36-32\lib\pickle.py", line 771, in save_tuple
    save(element)
  File "C:\Programs_RD\Python\Python36-32\lib\pickle.py", line 549, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "C:\Programs_RD\Python\Python36-32\lib\pickle.py", line 662, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "C:\Programs_RD\Python\Python36-32\lib\pickle.py", line 504, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "C:\Programs_RD\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\dill\_dill.py", line 893, in save_module_dict
    StockPickler.save_dict(pickler, obj)
  File "C:\Programs_RD\Python\Python36-32\lib\pickle.py", line 856, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.items())
  File "C:\Programs_RD\Python\Python36-32\lib\pickle.py", line 882, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "C:\Programs_RD\Python\Python36-32\lib\pickle.py", line 549, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "C:\Programs_RD\Python\Python36-32\lib\pickle.py", line 662, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "C:\Programs_RD\Python\Python36-32\lib\pickle.py", line 504, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "C:\Programs_RD\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\dill\_dill.py", line 893, in save_module_dict
    StockPickler.save_dict(pickler, obj)
  File "C:\Programs_RD\Python\Python36-32\lib\pickle.py", line 856, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.items())
  File "C:\Programs_RD\Python\Python36-32\lib\pickle.py", line 882, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "C:\Programs_RD\Python\Python36-32\lib\pickle.py", line 504, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "C:\Programs_RD\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\dill\_dill.py", line 893, in save_module_dict
    StockPickler.save_dict(pickler, obj)
  File "C:\Programs_RD\Python\Python36-32\lib\pickle.py", line 856, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.items())
  File "C:\Programs_RD\Python\Python36-32\lib\pickle.py", line 887, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "C:\Programs_RD\Python\Python36-32\lib\pickle.py", line 549, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "C:\Programs_RD\Python\Python36-32\lib\pickle.py", line 662, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "C:\Programs_RD\Python\Python36-32\lib\pickle.py", line 504, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "C:\Programs_RD\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\dill\_dill.py", line 893, in save_module_dict
    StockPickler.save_dict(pickler, obj)
  File "C:\Programs_RD\Python\Python36-32\lib\pickle.py", line 856, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.items())
  File "C:\Programs_RD\Python\Python36-32\lib\pickle.py", line 882, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "C:\Programs_RD\Python\Python36-32\lib\pickle.py", line 524, in save
    rv = reduce(self.proto)
TypeError: can't pickle _tkinter.tkapp objects
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. When you ask questions there should be no long and irrelevant code in your question. Otherwise no-one will bother to answer you! You state that you've already reduced it a lot, but looking at this code I actually have no idea what it is supposed to do and no idea where it is getting stuck. Try to slim down your question to the specific problem you are having: something runs and everything freezes. Post only what that something is and how you run it. Make sure the code you post is runnable (no errors) and that we  know what Python version you are using

Comment: Ok, I will work on that right now. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A process is started by calling start() on it, which will setup the process run method to run in a separate process.

So try replacing: `self.slave_process.run()` with `self.slave_process.start()`

It's explained here :https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=process#multiprocessing.Process

Comment: Hey! I have changed the code and now it returns an error code.

Comment: I would love to ask another question as it seems to be another problem but I need an upvote to do so!